# How do I clear a breakpoint from the processor after GDB is killed?

Tags: debugging, gdb

I was debugging a Free Pascal application in GDB running in a Linux environment over SSH when my SSH connection dropped. I have seen from experience that GDB is closed when this happens, and to be sure, I ran `pidof gdb` and nothing returned. I reopened GDB and attached to the same running application and I was able to continue debugging and finished up after a few minutes. An hour after I had finished debugging, the application died unexpectedly. The only log I have reflecting what happened is this:

```
Nov  5 16:29:59 kernel: [846469.866825] traps: Maintain[9065] trap int3 ip:7f5148924cf1 sp:7f51376a4420 error:0
```

After a bit of research, it seems that a sigtrap sent to an application will kill it unless it is caught by the debugger. My assumption is that this signal was caused by the program hitting the breakpoint that I had set, and GDB was no longer available to catch the signal.

Here are my questions:

1. Is it possible for GDB to leave the breakpoint trap in the processor after being closed unexpectedly?
2. If that is the case, is there some way to clear the breakpoint from the processor after it has been applied and then unexpectedly closed?

Answer (score 0):

> My assumption is that this signal was caused by the program hitting the breakpoint that I had set

That assumption is likely incorrect: GDB removes all breakpoints when it detaches from the process automatically.

It looks like the trap address `7f5148924cf1` belongs to some shared library.

If you have a core dump, or recorded the location of shared libraries when the process was alive, you can examine the library that was loaded at that address, and see what instruction is there. Chances are: it's an `int3` that has nothing to do with any GDB breakpoints. It is not that uncommon to put `__asm__("INT3")` or `__asm__(UD2)` into "can't happen" branch, effectively implementing `assert` that can't be compiled out.

Another possibility: your app jumped through a wild function pointer.

I just looked at `objdump -d` for my `libpthread.so.0`, and I see a lot of `INT3`s:

```
__pthread_initialize_minimal:
...
    9479:       b8 00 40 00 00          mov    $0x4000,%eax
    947e:       e9 8f fe ff ff          jmpq   9312 <__pthread_initialize_minimal+0x1f2>
    9483:       cc                      int3   
    9484:       cc                      int3   
    9485:       cc                      int3   
    9486:       cc                      int3   
    9487:       cc                      int3   
    9488:       cc                      int3   
    9489:       cc                      int3   

sigcancel_handler:
...
    950c:       e8 2f 9e 00 00          callq  13340 <__pthread_unwind>
    9511:       cc                      int3   
    9512:       cc                      int3   
    9513:       cc                      int3   
    9514:       cc                      int3
```

etc. If the application ever lands on e.g. `0x9511`, or any of the other `INT3`s, it will die with `SIGTRAP` just like your app did.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, it does seem extremely coincidental to me that it would occur around the same time as my debugging. However, I suppose I can't make any assumptions. Thanks again!